# CodeIgniter 3 404 error for controller/method

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

i am using CodeIgniter 3 i have created routes in routes.php for example `$route['mothertongue'] = 'Mother_tongue/index';`  but for few pages i have directly applied controller/method for example http://localhost/project_folder/student/category/ the problem is when i type http://localhost/project_folder/mothertongue/aaa it shows 404 page which i created which is fine but when i type http://localhost/project_folder/student/category/aaaa which does not exists same page means http://localhost/project_folder/student/category/ page is loaded and 404 page do not load.

my route file is

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'home';
```

$route['404_override'] = 'errors';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;

i searched and found that if controller is not found then 404_override gets triggered. What should i do to redirect every url which does not exists

my htacces file is

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```